# how to add auto texview scroll like google translator

Tags: java, android

how to add HorizontalScrollView: auto-scroll to end when new Views are added in textview like this image i want to create this type of textview it scoll when i type text plz anybody help me?

[image].

My Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.textviewdemo.MainActivity">


    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Name"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


    <TextView
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
        android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

My Main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText editText;
    TextView textView;
    HorizontalScrollView horizontalScrollView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                textView.setText(s);
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Wrap** your `TextView` with a `HorizontalScrollView` as below and remove `android:scrollHorizontally="true"`

```
<HorizontalScrollView
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
     android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView" >

     <TextView
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
         android:textSize="30dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
         android:id="@+id/textView" />

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

**Modify** your `onCreate()` as below:

```
EditText editText;
TextView textView;
HorizontalScrollView horizontalScrollView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        editText =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        textView =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        horizontalScrollView =(HorizontalScrollView)findViewById(R.id.horizontalScrollView);

        editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                textView.setText(s);
                horizontalScrollView.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        horizontalScrollView.fullScroll(HorizontalScrollView.FOCUS_RIGHT);
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }
        });               

    }
```